# When is $f_r$ upper semicontinuous or lower semicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space. $r$ is a real number. V is an open set in X. Define $f_r (x)=r$ if $x \in V$, otherwise =0. When is $f_r$ upper semicontinuous or lower semicontinuous?

This $f_r$ is the ingredient of Urysohn's Lemma.

Comment: Usually around 1am.

Comment: @copper.hat what do you say?

Comment: It is a joke. Consider three cases, $r=0$, r>0$ and $r<0$.

Comment: Really? I was considering r=1, since it is the indicator function when r=1. And the indicator function of open set is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: The answer depends on $r$.

Comment: Yes, but how many cases of r?

Comment: Emm, are you reading my comments?

Comment: Great, I figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: That is great. Well done!